# Android apps: Retrieving "Me" contact from the contact list

Tags: android, import, contacts, picker

I am poking around with importing data from contact list on android. In the emulator I notice a topped contact group, which contains only one contact for myself. The rest of the contacts follows below.

[image: image 1]

However, when I use the following code

```
Intent pickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(pickerIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

the picker does not show this contact for picking, only the rest of them:

[image: image 2]

My questions are:

1. How often would an android user want to import this special contact?
2. How can it be offered for picking in the picker?

Comment: Any solution found for this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve the owners profile for your own app, you should be using [ContactsContract.Profile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Profile.html). However, that is only for API 14+, so for versions below that, you're (unfortunately) limited to using a content provider and querying for the owners info using a known constant such as phone number, which is a major hack and may not always be reliable (and also not recommended).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, now there is no easy way for me to re-check this. I may come back to it, for the sake of curiosity.